# User search doesn't work when name field is empty

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, users, display-names

User search should use the account name when the user's "Name" field is blank.

Here are some accounts with blank names that aren't found when the names are typed into the search field on the [Users](https://serverfault.com/users) page:

- [~drpaulbrewer](https://serverfault.com/users/33903/drpaulbrewer)
- [mpbloch](https://serverfault.com/users/9076/mpbloch)
- [kubanskamac](https://serverfault.com/users/9461/kubanskamac)
- [icky2000](https://serverfault.com/users/33288/icky2000)

There's no particular significance to this list. It's just a bunch of accounts I found while preparing this post.

Comment: Also ~quack, formerly.

Comment: I found quack...

Comment: ...and I thought duck's quacks didn't [echo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QYHcQbGNhE)...

Answer (score 1):

These users don't actually have names; we're synthesizing a fake name based on their OpenID string.

edit: completed, because we no longer pretend to synthesize fake names from OpenIDs for users who have not provided one.

Comment: I think the OP's point was that this 'fake name' should still be searched through, because the searcher's expectation is that one should be able to find the profile of a user by their screen name, even if that user is not registered.

Comment: @Ether: **Yes**, that's what I mean. **Also**, I haven't tested this, but does the "@user" comment addressing work for replying to these users? Otherwise, maybe yelling "Hey, you!" loudly enough...

Comment: @dennis correct, that won't work either for users with no display name.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that this is no longer relevant, since the sites no longer generate display names based on OpenID. Though it is good to know that "@user191054" has no effect (see Jeff's comment to his own answer).