# User search doesn't find some users

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, users, user-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [user search doesn’t work when name field is empty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46757/user-search-doesnt-work-when-name-field-is-empty)

Some users aren't shown when performing a search on the [User page](https://stackoverflow.com/users). Whether I enter the full or partial name, they never show up.

Here is an [example user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/322247/davit-datuashvili). Note that the `name` field on his profile appears empty - this seems to be related. The username does appear correctly on the user's posts and in the title of the profile page.

More examples: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258935/objectivesea) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/242289/imhenke) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133589/grimbo)

Comment: This is a duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46757/user-search-doesnt-work-when-name-field-is-empty

Comment: Yes it is, I don't know how I missed that question... Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

The users chose to go in after the fact and delete their name, i.e. change it to nothing.  I'm not sure how they did this since it is supposed to require at least three characters, but since that was recently implemented, they might have done it before that went into effect.

Maybe they should track old user-names so that user search will work correctly (lots of details to consider for that one).

Comment: Their name is not empty though - it appears correctly on the title of the profile page and on all their posts. Only the `name` field on the profile page appears empty. I've edited my post to clarify this.

Comment: Can you imagine the nightmare if they tried to implement tracking old names on Meta?

Comment: Yep, it sounds a little nightmarish.

Answer (score 0):

That user actually has no name -- what you're seeing as a "name" is just inferred from the OpenID. So this is by design at the moment.