# Search on “Users” page broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, user-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [user search doesn’t work when name field is empty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46757/user-search-doesnt-work-when-name-field-is-empty)

It doesn’t find the user “[romkyns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33080)”, for example (user ID 33080). I suspect it searches only the “name” field, which in the case of romkyns is empty. It should find users by their userid too.

**EDIT:** The user has now filled in the “name” field, and apparently cannot change it back to empty. WTF! Anyway, so searching for romkyns will work now, but the bug is obviously still a bug.

Comment: It's fun to search for "|" (no quotes) too :)

Comment: "|" is a fuzzy kitty who is workin on ur problemz.

Comment: If the user doesn't have a display name, they can't receive comment replies either. Really, it's better practice to have a display name - you have no real benefit to changing it back to empty.

Comment: The underscore in user search appear to match any character just as with the SQL LIKE statement. For instance '___ Skeet'

Answer (score 2):

> in the case of romkyns is empty

Yes, if there is no username, there is no way to search by username. (what you're seeing here is us inferring a displayname based on the openid URL, which is otherwise not public.)

> It should find users by their userid too

If all you want to do is "find users by their userid" then simply enter `http://example.com/users/12345` in the address bar of your browser.